# C# overloading: method for null value

Tags: c#, overloading, overload-resolution

I am currently writing a serializer for some of my classes.
I created a set of static methods with the following signatures

```
public static string serialize(int val);
public static string serialize(string val);
public static string serialize(float val);
public static string serialize(MyOwnClass val);
public static string serialize(AnotherClass val);
public static string serialize(SomethingElse val);
```

Additionally, sometimes I have to deal with `null` values.
I would like to treat them in a special way, i.e. a signature like:

```
public static string serialize(null val);
```

The call to the function should be something like:

```
string s = serialize(someVariableThatMightBeNull);
```

And it should be triggered anytime `serialize` is called with the value `null`, independent of which type the variable was declared with.

Is there any way to implement this in C#?

Currently my only solution would be to add this line to each method:
(for datatypes that can be null):

```
if(val == null){ dealWithNull(); }
```

This solution seems a bit tedious, as I have about 30 different cases and I would prefer not having a dispatch method.

---

As an example, Xtend features `dispatch methods` that also offer the `Void` type which checks for null values.
[Xtend Dispatch Methods](https://eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/202_xtend_classes_members.html#polymorphic-dispatch)

Comment: By null values, you mean an object whose reference is `null` ? or the absence of parameter ?

Comment: added info to clarify the call

Comment: did you try an overload of `serialize(object value)`

Comment: @pm100 I did, it'll choose the string one first, before going into the object

Comment: @S.K. null isn't a type, did you pass null (the keyword) or did you pass a null string (in which case it's pretty normal that it went into the string one)? Also why aren't you handling this inside each of the serialize calls (checking for null?) How does it make sense to serialize null itself instead of the null property of a given type? If you want to add to a serialization Stream that "null" is present but not associate it with a given type why don't you make a custom method (not an overload) for it and name it AddNullToSerialization() which makes a lot more sense than serializing "null"?

Comment: @RonanThibaudau As mentioned above, I _could_ do it in each of these methods, but I have 30 of them and there is a high chance I'll have more in the future.

Comment: @S.K. The idea is the same if you have 1 10 100 or 1000 of those methods, you can factor the null case in it's own method and call that from each of those, odds are you can even refactor most of what you do (even in the non null case) into each of those, also unless you just want to be able to dezerialize "null" without knowing that it's null of type X (which sounds fairly useless hence the rest of my original comment) you need to know which type was null so you can't just escape the specific method as you need the type info. It would help if you told us what you want to serialize to and why

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly :

I'd go with a method signature waiting for an `object`.

The compiler will **ALWAYS** choose the method signature that seem the closest to what you used. So it will only use the method with the `object` signature if no other are available.

In this method, you will be able to check if the parameter is null and/or handle classes that does not have their own static method for serialization

---

For custom serialization, IMHO, I think it would be better to let each class handle themselves.

In order to do this, I'd define an Interface `ICustomSerialization` containing a method `string CustomSerialization()`

I'd then make each one of the classes I'd need to serialize inherit from this interface and implement the the method inside each class.

That would offer the benefit of having the serialization code IN the related class, avoid a **massive** serialization class.

Allow your serializer to work with interface (and thus not having to know how to handle each particular class)

Comment: I tried that, but I receive the message that the call is ambiguous between other classes that have been implemented. It doesn't choose `object` first. afaik the compiler will choose more specific methods first.
i.e. `string` would be possible as well as any of my own classes.

As for the serialization in each class: I cannot change them. (legacy code)

Comment: Passing a null value explicitely to a serialize method seems rather unintuitive for me. What would you want to serialize ? Ask yourself the question Would you call this method without any parameter ? If not, check the parameter for null before calling it and if it is do not call. (if you really want to do it anyway, a cast should do the trick)

Comment: the code is called with a variable (i.e `serialize(someVariableThatMightBeNull);` )

the variable might be declared of any type though.

Comment: Then either check for null before calling, or after. If you want to write minimal code, check inside each one of your static functions.

Comment: @S.K. When you call it with a VARIABLE that can be null it's not the same at all as when you call it with the KEYWORD null, in the later case there is no information about the type, in the former there is and it will go to whatever the type is, no way around it, so there is no way to make it so MyClassA goes to MethodA but instead goes to MethodANull if it is null, that's not something the language can provide and you need to handle this internally

Comment: @RonanThibaudau Yes, I guess are right. I'll handle it internally, or write a dispatch function myself. I only recently started with C# and hoped there would be some construct like the one in Xtend (see original post), as so far C# did have surprisingly handy language constructs.

Comment: @S.K. Since you just recently started with c# just checking so see no offense in this but you do know there is built in binary / xml and other types of serialisation already available right?

Comment: @RonanThibaudau None taken, advice are always welcome. I did research it beforehand. Unfortunately the code I'm writing has quite particular serialization. Using the built-in would mean lot of adaptation effort. On top of that it's legacy code... But let's not take this off-topic :-)

Answer (score 2):

The method that will be called depends on the type of the thing that is being passed in.

If you have something typed as `string` that holds a null, then it's going to hit the method with the string parameter. If you have something that's a `MyOwnClass` type variable and it's null, then it's going to hit the method with the `MyOwnClass` parameter.

I think your best option is to do something in the code that's external to this.

`if(whatever == null) { serializeNull(whatever); } else { serialize(whatever); }`

Comment: Yes, @Sidewinder94. I'd like to have a sort of "catch-all" for any kind of `null` value.

Comment: @S.K. you won't be able to do this using the strong typing. Any object in C# can be null.

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution is the only one in C# ([where you don't have true templates](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/07/30/whats-the-difference-part-one-generics-are-not-templates/)).

I think you might just be happy about it as long as the size of the boilerplate code stays small compared to the rest of the serialization code.

If it's acceptable for you to introduce a tight-coupling between your classes and the serialization code, then you can go the "OO" way to eliminate redundancy by introducing a base class that handles nulls and have each derived class override a virtual implementation method.

Answer (score 0):

So I've got a similar problem, except your workaround was not suitable for me, as I needed a different return type on the `null` overload. E.g. I needed `Tensor` == `Tensor` to return `Tensor<bool>`, and `Tensor` == `null` to return simply `bool`.

The way I solved it was the following trick, that works under the following assumptions:

1. `Tensor` is the most specific class, and is generally not supposed
   to be inherited.
2. There are no overloads of `==` with the second operand of reference type other than `Tensor`.

If that is the case, then you can simply define `class NullTensor: Tensor`, that can not be instantiated (private constructor only), and have overloads

- `Tensor` == `NullTensor` -> `bool`
- `Tensor` == `Tensor` -> `Tensor`

Then if you write `(Tensor)x == null`, the first overload would be picked over the second one, as `null` can be either `Tensor` or `NullTensor`, but the second type is more specific.